# How Poisson developed Poisson bracket?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, history, phase-space, poisson-brackets

In textbooks, they just give [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) used for restating the Hamiltonian in a powerful and elegant way. But why it is useful, and how Poisson created it?

Comment: you will have better chance for an answer here History of Science and Mathematics; see https://hsm.stackexchange.com/